# Upload and crop image with jQuery

Tags: jquery, cropper

I'm using jQuery to upload and crop image,link of this source is here:

[jQuery Awesome Cropper](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Simple-jQuery-Client-Side-Image-Cropping-Plugin-Awesome-Cropper.html)

I downloaded this code and used it, but the result I received is just as in the form below and the photo will not be uploaded

[image]

Comment: press F12, open devtools, and take a look what's wrong there.

Comment: there should be an error in console I believe!

Comment: @LevonGrigoryan I get this Error ` Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery`

Comment: yeah you need to load jquery before all the other scripts on your html page

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Make sure to load jquery.js file before loading bootstrap. This solved my problem.